# Singularity: Fatal authentication error when pulling public image

Tags: dockerhub, singularity-container

I am new to Singularity and trying to get my first definition file to work. However, I am getting a fatal authentication error when trying to build the definition file, even though I am pulling a public image.

First of all, building without use of a definition file works fine:

```
$ singularity build test.sif docker://ubuntu
INFO:    Starting build...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 8527c5f86ecc skipped: already exists  
Copying config 6e885d46c0 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
2022/04/29 13:59:40  info unpack layer: sha256:8527c5f86ecc162d68a9d38c8f4c6a6443158c67417e8bc2c3cea9f3868394eb
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
INFO:    Build complete: test.sif
```

However, now I try to do what I think is the same using a definition file called `test.def`:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu
```

and the output is:

```
$ sudo singularity build test.sif test.def 
INFO:    Starting build...
FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

I have checked both my `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD` and `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME` variables, and they are both empty:

```
$ echo $SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD

$ echo $SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check the output of `singularity remote list` and `sudo singularity remote list`. When you run sudo it uses the root user's default environment, which may differ from yours unexpectedly. If you `sudo -i` to become the root user and attempt to build the image does that work?

Comment: Are the values of `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD` and `SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME ` different for the root user (i.e. running with `sudo`)?

Comment: @tsnowlan adding docker.io with `sudo singularity remote login` did the trick, though I am still very confused about why I have to login to Docker Hub to access a public image.